# Azure Publish Setting

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I am trying to deploy the cloud service, so on visual studio I select the account and then it brings the "Choose your subscription" dropdown which has the correct subscription name.

however on click of "Next" it pops up the "Create Storage Account" dialog box. I already have created a storage account in the Azure under the same subscription. So i do not want to create one.

Any thoughts on what I may be missing.

Comment: One reason could be that the storage that i created was not the classic storage. So most likely visual studio is looking for classic storage.

Comment: It is entirely possible. Was your Cloud Service created in the old portal?

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, the Storage should be created in the "Classic" mode. This more appears to be an issue with Visual Studio not recognizing the non-classic storage.

Hopefully MS would issue a fix.